# How to make crypto.randomBytes() to replace Math.random()

Tags: node.js

I need a cryptographically secure random number generator to replace `Math.random()`

I came across `crypto.randomBytes()` however, it returns a byte array. What is a way to make the byte array into 0-1 ( so that it is compatible with `Math.random`)

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32LE() / 0xffffffff;
```

randomBytes generates 4 random bytes, which are then read as a 32-bit unsigned integer in little endian. The max value of a 32bit unsigned int is 0xffffffff (or 4,294,967,295 in decimal). By dividing the randomly generated 32bit int by its max value you get a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Why 8 random bytes for a 32-bit integer? Should be 4 bytes.

Comment: Correct, should be `crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32LE() / 0xffffffff;`

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer. No idea why I put 8, although it doesn't affect the outcome

Comment: @Sigmatics looks like Node expect an offset parameter in readUInt32LE() method, which isn't really provided here.

Comment: @Sigmatics `crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32LE(0) / 0xffffffff;`

Comment: `offset` has the default value 0: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#bufreaduint32leoffset

Comment: My Safari browser says `TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function. (In 'crypto.randomBytes(4)', 'crypto.randomBytes' is undefined)` and TypeScript says `Property 'randomBytes' does not exist on type 'Crypto'.`

Answer (score 0):

For reactJS or node JS server side we can do as mention below

Below code will always return under the 100000

```js
 const crypto = require('crypto'); 
 crypto.randomBytes(1)[0] * 200
```

It will also return always under the 100000

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000)
```

For Ex:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like:

```
var randomVal = (crypto.randomBytes(1)[0] / 255);
```

Comment: But Math.random() has a very very long tail of decimal places between 0 and 1 whereas this essentially means there are only 255 options between 0 to 1. Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: Ultimately it depends on what you're currently doing with the result of `Math.random()` in order to suggest a better alternative.

Comment: I am making a javascript game and am trying to shuffle an array in an unpredictable way (http://underscorejs.org/#shuffle); This shuffle function depends on Math.random so I wanted to replace it

Comment: @samol - so why isn't `Math.random()` good enough for that purpose?  What evidence do you have that it isn't plenty good?

Comment: The client told me to use crypto.randomBytes() (so that people can't predict it) but for the life of me can't figure out how to replicate Math.random